# Save list of summary objects in R

Tags: r, dataframe, regression

I have a dataframe with columns y, x{1,1},...,x{n,m}

( N rows ~ 1 million and (n*m+1) columns ), n ~ 100, m ~ 10

I need to save summary of n independent regressions reg_i : y ~ x{i,1} + x{i,2} + ... + x{i,m}

I am able to save them individually (in separate files) using save() .

How can I save it as a list in a single file that I can later load for post-processing without having to run the regression again?

An example below:

```
> df = data.frame( y = sample.int(100,5 ), x11 = sample.int(100,5 ), x12 = sample.int(100,5 ), x13 = sample.int(100,5 ), x21 = sample.int(100,5 ), x22 = sample.int(100,5 ), x23 = sample.int(100,5 ) )
> df
   y x11 x12 x13 x21 x22 x23
1 16  18  51  55  55  72  22
2 34  33  55  79  70  26  26
3  2  88  46  28 100  84  11
4  3  60  32  92  76  83  75
5 74  31  74  51  64  71  63
> 
> v1 = summary( lm( y ~ x11 + x12 + x13, data = df) )
> v2 = summary( lm( y ~ x21 + x22 + x23, data = df) )
```

Here I have to define v1 and v2 as separate variable. How can I make it like v[1] and v[2], and save v ?

Edit:

I also have a column z which categorizes my input data into ~10 classes ( z in {1...10} )

I want to regress separately on these classes of z as well

( number of regressions = n * length(unique(z) ) )

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example

Comment: You _could_ just use `save.image` to save your whole environment.  Otherwise, `save` will save multiple objects: `save(rg1, rg2, rg3)`  How big is `n` ?

Comment: `lst <- mget(ls(pattern = "<regressions names pattern>")); save(lst)`?

Answer (score 0):

We can do this in a loop

```
lst1 <- lapply(list(names(df)[2:4], names(df)[5:7]),
       function(nm) summary(lm(reformulate(nm, 'y'), data = df)))
```